# How can i persist the data in a Web API method until all pages data is received?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am developing a Web API using .NET Core. I have a method `SynchroniseUsersAsync` which receives batches of users page by page. Below is the code sample.

```
[HttpPost("SyncroniseUsersAsync")]
public async Task<IActionResult> SyncroniseUsers([FromBody] UserPageData userPageData)
{
    // I want to keep UserPageData in a persistence list until the last page is received.

    if(userPageData.IsLastPage)
    {
        // Once the last page is received, perform some calculations on the
        // persistence list and save it into the database.

        return Ok();
    }

    return BadRequest();
}
```

I have another Windows service that consumes this Web API using HttpClient. The service collects user's data which could be thousands of users so we need to post all these users page by page and when the last batch is posted we set `IsLastPage=true`.

As the HTTP is a stateless protocol when I make multiple requests the previous page data is lost. I can't persist the batches in a list so that I receive all the sets and process once the last page is received.

Please suggest.

Comment: By registering an object as a singleton using AddSingleton(), allowing shared state between multiple API requests.

Comment: you can also use a in memory cache or some cache store like redis , other than that you could also store the whole list in db as a json response as well

Comment: Why not send it all in one request? If you say "because of the size" that must mean you're worried about memory usage - so why not use a database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few ways to persist data until last page received

- Using Databse
- Using caching
- In-memory data structure
- File storage
- Session state

1)Using database

You can use a persistent storage mechanism to store the user data between requests.
Below is the sample code

```
[HttpPost("SyncroniseUsersAsync")]
public async Task<IActionResult> SyncroniseUsers([FromBody] UserPageData userPageData)
{
    if (!userPageData.IsLastPage)
    {
        await _userRepository.SaveUserPageDataAsync(userPageData);
    }
    else
    {
        var allUserPageData = await _userRepository.GetAllUserPageDataAsync();

        await ProcessUserData(allUserPageData);

        await _userRepository.ClearUserPageDataAsync();

        return Ok();
    }

    return BadRequest();
}
```

2)By using caching

You can use an in-memory cache to store the user data until the last page is received.

```
[HttpPost("SyncroniseUsersAsync")]
public async Task<IActionResult> SyncroniseUsers([FromBody] UserPageData userPageData, [FromServices] IMemoryCache memoryCache)
{
    if (userPageData.IsLastPage)
    {
        // Perform calculations on the cached user data
        var allUserPageData = memoryCache.Get<List<UserPageData>>("UserPageData");

        // Process the user data
        await ProcessUserData(allUserPageData);

        // Clear the cached user data
        memoryCache.Remove("UserPageData");

        return Ok();
    }

    var cachedUserPageData = memoryCache.Get<List<UserPageData>>("UserPageData");

    if (cachedUserPageData == null)
    {
        cachedUserPageData = new List<UserPageData>();
    }

    cachedUserPageData.Add(userPageData);

    memoryCache.Set("UserPageData", cachedUserPageData);

    return BadRequest();
}
```

3)File storage

Instead of using a database or caching, you can write received data to temporary files on the server. Each file can correspond to a synchronization task identified by `SyncId`. When the last page is received, you can read the data from these files, perform calculations, and then delete the files.

Comment: Thanks for all these options. I think to keep performance in mind i would go with the caching option.